# HTML Cross browser issues on website

Tags: html, margin

Normally I'm able to fix my HTML errors by myself since it's not that complicated, but this time, I'm having a hard one.

I decided to change my navigation on my website and most of it works well & most browsers displays it correctly.

Where my problem is tho, is that I have a 5-6px margin I cannot find where is coming from. The link & image showing my problem will be below.

My second problem is that IE7 shows a huge margin, and again, I cant spot where it's coming from.

The webpage URL is: [Deaglegame.net](http://deaglegame.net) & below here is the image:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SBP9.png]

I'm leaving for work in a couple hours, so if I dont reply it's not because I dont wanna reply, I'll check this thread as soon as possible, but any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks to anyone willing to help!

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=95e06cbe-4940-4218-b75d-b8856fced535 lets you examine the page's DOM, along the lines of Firefox's Firebug.

Comment: i cant see the img link because my work blocks that site for some reason :(.  can anybody tell me where his margin is?  is it the bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Mmerrell's fix for `div#main` should sort one half of the issue. Next comes @Bumble Bee's observation for your `ul#navigation li a span` styles. The padding of the `SPAN` elements is causing your links to push the content.

```
/* deaglegame.css (line 48) */ 
#navigate li:hover a span, 
#navigate li.hover a span, 
#navigate li.active a span {
    /* removed  padding: 12px 0 0; */
}

/* deaglegame.css (line 30) */ 
#navigate li a span {
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    height: 38px;
    line-height: 2.5;
    /* removed padding: 12px 0 0; */
    position: relative;
}
```

Drop the padding on them and set the `line-height` property. In general, it's better to use `line-height` for the vertical positioning of text (it applies to content of both block and inline elements) in place of `padding`.

Comment: wow, there is still 1px left, but i can manage with that. thanks alot for this, greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thanks, but in all honesty I think Mmerrell should get the credit for this one.

Answer (score 2):

The IE7 Issue is due to compatibility view.  This will be forced on you by default if you are visiting the page through an intranet address.  You can get around this issue by dropping the bottom padding and setting the height to 175px: for the main div.  This also seems to fix the margin issue when running compatibility view.

You menu item list is somehow causing the margin issue outside of compatibility view, I would suggest when running IE to hit F12 and that should open Developer tools, that is how I found these settings that needed to be adjusted.

Comment: Thanks alot for this reply, but the margin did reduce while removing the padding & putting the height, although there is a still a 3px or so. But thanks again! really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Check the image below, which might solve your first problem. Try to specify a lesser value for the padding there. Consider using a tool like firebug to resolve this kind of issues.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using YUI CSS reset in the future (or perhaps even integrating it now), http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/cssreset/ . I've found it helps me considerably when designing cross-browser compatible sites, and has almost eliminated weird margin or padding errors I come across.